# puppet: nagios service subscribe not working

Tags: nagios, puppet

I've just set up puppet to generate nagios config files, which is great :) I have the services being put into a file named as `$nagios_puppet_service_file` and here is part of the nagios service class:

```
  file { $nagios_puppet_service_file:
    ensure => file,
    owner  => nagios, group => admins, mode => '0664',
    notify => Service['nagios'],
  }

  Nagios_host <<||>>
  Nagios_hostextinfo <<||>>
  Nagios_service <<||>>

  service { 'nagios':
    ensure     => running,
    enable     => true,
    subscribe  => [ File[$nagios_puppet_host_file], File[$nagios_puppet_hostextinfo_file],
                    File[$nagios_puppet_service_file], ],
    hasrestart => true,
    hasstatus  => true,
  }
```

While one of my service definitions looks like:

```
$real_nagios_http_port = $nagios_http_port ? { '' => '80',  default => $nagios_http_port }
$real_nagios_http_url  = $nagios_http_url  ? { '' => '/',   default => $nagios_http_url  }
$real_nagios_http_addr = $nagios_http_addr ? { '' => $fqdn, default => $nagios_http_addr }


@@nagios_service { "check_http_port_${hostname}":
  use                 => 'generic-service',
  check_command       => "check_http_port!$real_nagios_http_addr!$real_nagios_http_port!$real_nagios_http_url",  
  service_description => 'HTTP service',
  host_name           => $hostname,
  target              => $nagios_puppet_service_file,
}
```

So the service file is generated correctly, but the nagios service is not restarted, despite the `subscribe` clause in the service part above. (Well, sometimes it is restarted when the permissions on the file are updated, but that doesn't always happen on a puppet run, and sometimes happens part way through a puppet run, so only some changes get loaded, despite them all being in the services file.)

Any ideas why the subscribe clause isn't working as expected? Can I subscribe to all nagios_service instances some how? Would a notify in the nagios_service bit work any better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of the file are not being controlled by the `file` statement, which is the one with the `notify`. You should put `notify` on `nagios_service`.

And while there isn't a way to make `service` subscribe to all `nagios_service`, you can do it the other way around like this:

```
Nagios_service <<||>> { notify => Service['nagios'] }
```

But I see no reason for this `notify` attribute not to be defined on the exported instances of `nagios_service` to begin with.